# How can I extract from mysql the logged in user id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to extract from users table the user id, but it doesn't work.

Login function:

```
function login($user, $password) {
$user = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($user));
$password = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($password));

$password = md5($password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$user' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error. ' . mysql_error());


if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
    $_SESSION['access']=true;
    $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
    $_SESSION["password"] = $password; 
    $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
    header('Location: '.DIR.'admin.php');
    exit;
}
else
{
    //error
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Wrong name or password.';
}
}
```

Now when i'm logged in, i tried to post these info on admin.php with echo 'Username ' .$user. 'ID: ' .$id '; it doesn't show.

Comment: Can you post `admin.php` code ?

Comment: Use PDO. It has more swag.

Comment: Please don't use `strip_tags()`. Users should be able to use `<` in my passwords, and `echo strip_tags('foo<bar');` just prints `foo`. Characters like `<` and `>` do not cause problems in the database but they may cause issues when used in html. You should resolve the issue there.

Answer (score 1):

You should change line

```
if (mysql_num_rows($rezultat) == 1)
```

into

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
```

But definitely you should consider using PDO with prepared statements to prevent SQL injection or at least mysqli functions (mysql is deprecated now)

Comment: and not store plain text passwrods

Comment: He doesn't. He uses md5 but of course it is also not the best method

Comment: doh missed that line :( of course md5 is so broke its *almost* as bad

Answer (score 0):

The query is wrong, correct to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '" . $user . "' AND password = '" . $password . "'";
```

Probably you don't have an user with name '$user'. Pay attention on quotation marks.

Comment: Actually, the query is correct. PHP replaces variables in double quoted strings with their contents.

Comment: Even when the variables are in double quotes but surrounded by single quotes?

Comment: Yes. The single quotes are literal single quotes in the string and do not affect the variable replacement.

Comment: HUmmm, interesting. But IMHO, is odd to use, when we care about code readability.